# Getting Original Coordinate Before Transformations

Tags: java, graphics2d

I'm creating a program involving hexagon grids, and I use the code below for doing transformations:

```
    g2d.translate((double) WIDTH / 2, (double) HEIGHT / 2);
    g2d.scale(scale, scale);
    g2d.translate(-(double) WIDTH / 2, -(double) HEIGHT / 2);
    g2d.translate(translationX, translationY);
```

When I click on my mouse, the program is supposed to check if the hexagons contains the point in them, but it doesn't work after applying the transformations. Does anyone know how to revert back the transformations so I can get the position of the mouse before applying the transformations? I've tried a few formulas but none seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`g2d.getTransform()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#getTransform()) to get the current transformation matrix, then use its [`inverseTransform()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#inverseTransform(java.awt.geom.Point2D,%20java.awt.geom.Point2D)) method to transform a point from pixel coordinates on the canvas into logical coordinates in your current coordinate system.